# What's the differnce between "Set as Default Device" and "Set as Default Communications Device" in the Sound configuration in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio, hdmi

I noticed that there are two similar options in the "Sound" (Soundcard Configuration window->playback tab in the context menu) window in Windows 7.

What is the difference between these two options?

- "Set as Default Communications Device"
- "Set as Default Device"

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is a blog about it [here](http://louisgale.blogspot.com/2009/08/live-messenger-and-default.html).

- **Set as default device** - All programs will have their audio played through this device (unless otherwise configured)
- **Set as default communications device** - All calls/video call audio will be played through this device (unless otherwise configured)

Comment: This makes sense concerning playback devices. For recording devices and microphones, I do not understand the distinction.

Comment: You could choose to use a high-quality microphone for conferencing, gaming, etc. but leave your laptop's microphone as the default for basic voice commands.