# How can I separate my speaker and headphones sound?

Tags: windows, audio, skype, speakers, headphones

I am using Windows 7, and I want to separate the sounds of my headphones and speakers so I can talk to my friends on Skype while my parents are listening to music on the speakers. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: See: [http://superuser.com/questions...](http://superuser.com/questions/140978/whats-the-differnce-between-set-as-default-device-and-set-as-default-communi)

Comment: Also http://superuser.com/questions/290530/how-to-listen-to-music-while-my-speaker-plays-something-else?
http://superuser.com/questions/68534/how-do-i-enable-multiple-audio-outputs-on-windows-7

Answer (score 3):

Most applications have specified input and output settings.  I believe Skype has the option to change setting through their Tools > Options menu.  Here you can change the input and output of Skype as an application by using the drop down to select input and output, your headphone and mic on the headset.  To make the rest of the computer's sounds, specifically your music, play through the speakers you would need to just set the default devices through your PC's audio settings to be the speakers for output.  This can be found in the control panel, Hardware and Sound > Sound > Playback > then choose the speakers you want the music to play through.

Answer (score 0):

You need an extra SoundCard, I had a similar problem while trying to play videogames with headphones and my brothers wanting to listen to music trough the speakers. I used a similar sound card to this one: http://goo.gl/rJu25K

That way you could plug the speakers to the computer and your headphones to the little sound card, you'll have to configure skype to go through the little sound card and the music player to go through the computer's sound card

Answer (score 0):

I am very late to this however this could be used by anyone that still has the problem:

I have an audio output port at the back of my monitor, I make my skype sound come out of the monitor and then I just plug in my headphones! Skype comes out your headphones and the rest out the speakers.

Comment: Could you expand your answer (ideally with screenshots) on how you did this?

Answer (score -1):

Try this ---> http://www.chevolume.com/

There is a trial of 7 days. Personally, I bought it after the trial !

That's nice and easy to use !

Hope it'll help you !